# Logging to NLog in Hangfire.io

Tags: c#, nlog, hangfire

I am currently using Hangfire to run some jobs in a windows service.  The jobs are fired from a WebAPI.

My system is currently working fine when all jobs succeed, but I am getting no logging for when exceptions occur.  Has anyone got any experience in using a custom logger to receive messages from Hangfire?

My logger is a basic NLog interface:

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public readonly NLog.Logger logger;

    public Logger(string name)
    {
        if (LogManager.Configuration == null)
        {
            FallbackInitialisation();
        }

        logger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
    }

    public Trace(string message)
    //etc.
}
```

I am configuring my Hangfire job server in my windows service like so:

```
SqlServerStorage storage = new SqlServerStorage("myConnectionString");
BackgroundJobServerOptions options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions();
m_server = new BackgroundJobServer(options, storage);
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
```

Based on the [hangfire documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/adding-logging.html), I simply tried following it by adding the required references, and adding the following after my job server setup, however there were still no logs produced:

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["configType"] = "INLINE";
LogManager.Adapter = new NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter(properties);
```

I am simply simulating an exception by `throw new Exception()` in the method called by the job. The job is created in the webApi call like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public void TestStartJob()
{
    m_logger.Trace("TestStartJob");
    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => m_service.TestStartJob());
}
```

What I am looking for, is if anyone has any experience in getting logging properly configured for use with Hangfire.

Comment: HangFire logs all exceptions in table HangFire.State. Are you sure that you need more logging?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov yes, I am aware that this exists, and I can see the exceptions in the hangfire web interface, but I would like to be able to see the exceptions in our own logs so that it can be detected both through web app and through logging when something falls over

Comment: If `AutomaticRetryAttribute` does not produce any logs on exception, it seems to me that logging isn't working entirely. Can you say me what versions of Common.Logging do you use and what package and version do you use for Common.Logging NLog adapter?

Comment: was trying with common.logging 2.2.0 as this was what Hangfire was requiring.  as the for common.logging nlog adapter, I was at first struggling to find one compatible, as the base one is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue by using the following versions of nuget packages:

```
NLog - 3.1
Common.Logging - 2.2.0
JVW.Logging.CommonLoggingNLogAdapter -  1.0.0.1
```

and then configuring the logging as such

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["configType"] = "INLINE";
Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new NLogFactoryAdapter(properties);
```